# A function $f : A \to C$ is continuous if and only if all restrictions $f|_{A_i},i=1,..,r$ are continuous.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

$A$ is the union of closed sets $A_1,..,A_r \subseteq C$

Further show that in case of arbitrary sets $A_i, f$ might not be continuous.

I think I have managed to prove the first part, however I'm stuck on the second part. Also I'm doubtful about the proof of the first part, so any short method for that would also be helpful.

Comment: For the second part, just note that the restriction of $f$ on any single point  is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Look at $A_1 = [0,1)$ and $A_2 = [1,2]$. Define $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in A_1$ and $f(x) = 2$ if $x \in A_2$.

If you want commentary on the first part you should post what you did.